# POSIX Threads and SIGSEGV

Tags: pthreads, segmentation-fault

I have a system with 10+ threads. I have a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV. if one thread generates SIGSEGV, does that signal go to all threads, or just to the thread that generated the signal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SIGSEGV` is a synchronous signal. It'll be delivered to the thread that caused the invalid memory access. From [`signal(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> A signal may be generated (and thus pending) for a process as a whole (e.g.,
>        when sent using `kill(2)`) or for a specific thread (e.g., certain signals, such
>        as `SIGSEGV` and `SIGFPE`, generated as a consequence of executing a specific
>        machine-language instruction are thread directed, as are signals targeted at a
>        specific thread using `pthread_kill(3)`).  A process-directed signal may be
>        delivered to any one of the threads that does not currently have the signal
>        blocked.  If more than one of the threads has the signal unblocked, then the
>        kernel chooses an arbitrary thread to which to deliver the signal.

Comment: Thanks. This verbiage is not in the MacOS X signal documentation.